# QListWidget with both text and icon items

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a GUI with a series of QListWidgets, and the first QListWidget should have both text items and Icon items, with the icon's label to the side. And the items of the other QListWidgets should align with the first QListWidget's item rows. I wondered if this was possible?

Here is what I have now:

[image]

This would be the goal:

[image]

Comment: Is the height of each corresponding item (the other items that belong to another QListWidget but that are in the same row) is governed by the first QListWidget? On the other hand if you are using PySide2 it uses that label and not PySide since a solution in PySide does not necessarily work in PySide2 and vice versa

Comment: I am using PySide2. Right now, the heights of the QListWidgets are not governed by the first QListWidget, and am populating the each QListWidget separately and the rows just lined up because the items were the same size.  The title labels aligning over the QListWidget worked really great after using the grid layout you advised, although you doesnt see that result in the pictures I posted here.

Comment: For this requirement, I prefer use QTableWidget

Comment: @winteralfs Also, will all QListWidget always have the same number of rows?

Comment: yes, they will have the same number of rows always.

Comment: I have no problem with that, I will just have to learn that method and practice with it, as I do not have a lot of experience with it and I am still learning. But I am open to any idea.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I see, yes, I will do this from now on, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I have created a single tree-shaped model where each branch is what each QListView should show. Then through a delegate that tracks the size of the items in the first QListView, the same size is set to the other corresponding items in the model through the SizeHintRole role, so the other QListView will use that information:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class AlignDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(AlignDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom


class IconAlignDelegate(AlignDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        s = super(IconAlignDelegate, self).sizeHint(option, index)
        row_parent = index.parent().row()
        r, model = index.row(), index.model()
        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            if i != row_parent:
                root_ix = model.index(i, 0)
                child_ix = model.index(r, 0, root_ix)
                model.setData(child_ix, s, QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole)
        return s


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        datas = [
            {"data": ["name1", "1", "1", "entity1", "path1"]},
            {"data": ["name2", "2", "2", "entity2", "path2"]},
            {"data": ["name3", "3", "3", "entity3", "path3"]},
            {
                "icon": "img2.png",
                "data": ["name4", "4", "4", "entity4", "path4"],
            },
            {"data": ["name5", "5", "5", "entity5", "path5"]},
        ]

        titles = ("Name", "C-ver", "L-ver", "Entity Name", "Path")

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 1, self)
        for i, title in enumerate(titles):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(title)
            model.setItem(i, 0, it)

        for r, data in enumerate(datas):
            path_icon = data.get("icon")
            for c, text in enumerate(data["data"]):
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                if c == 0 and path_icon is not None:
                    it.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(path_icon))
                parent_item = model.item(c, 0)
                parent_item.setChild(r, 0, it)

        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            lv = QtWidgets.QListView()
            if i == 0:
                lv.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
                delegate = IconAlignDelegate(lv)
            else:
                delegate = AlignDelegate(lv)
            lv.setItemDelegate(delegate)
            lv.setModel(model)
            root_index = model.index(i, 0)
            title = root_index.data()
            lv.setRootIndex(root_index)
            grid_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(title), 0, i)
            grid_layout.addWidget(lv, 1, i)

        # To understand better the structure of the model
        # uncomment the following lines
        # treeview = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        # treeview.setModel(model)
        # treeview.expandAll()
        # grid_layout.addWidget(treeview, 2, 0, 1, 5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

The previous method uses the SizeHintRole so it probably establishes the size and not only the height of the items, using the same strategy it is better to establish a new role that stores only the height:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

HeightRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 100


class AlignDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(AlignDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom


class IconAlignDelegate(AlignDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        s = super(IconAlignDelegate, self).sizeHint(option, index)
        row_parent = index.parent().row()
        r, model = index.row(), index.model()
        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            if i != row_parent:
                root_ix = model.index(i, 0)
                child_ix = model.index(r, 0, root_ix)
                model.setData(child_ix, s.height(), HeightRole)
        return s


class OtherDelegate(AlignDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        s = super(OtherDelegate, self).sizeHint(option, index)
        height = index.data(HeightRole)
        if height is not None:
            s.setHeight(height)
        return s


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        datas = [
            # icon, name, c_ver, l_ver, entity_name, path
            {"data": ["name1", "1", "1", "entity1", "path1"]},
            {"data": ["name2", "2", "2", "entity2", "path2"]},
            {"data": ["name3", "3", "3", "entity3", "path3"]},
            {
                "icon": "img2.png",
                "data": ["name4", "4", "4", "entity4", "path4"],
            },
            {"data": ["name5", "5", "5", "entity5", "path5"]},
        ]

        titles = ("Name", "C-ver", "L-ver", "Entity Name", "Path")

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 1, self)
        for i, title in enumerate(titles):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(title)
            model.setItem(i, 0, it)

        for r, data in enumerate(datas):
            path_icon = data.get("icon")
            for c, text in enumerate(data["data"]):
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                if c == 0 and path_icon is not None:
                    it.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(path_icon))
                parent_item = model.item(c, 0)
                parent_item.setChild(r, 0, it)

        splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter()
        lay.addWidget(splitter)

        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            lv = QtWidgets.QListView()
            if i == 0:
                lv.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
                delegate = IconAlignDelegate(lv)
            else:
                delegate = OtherDelegate(lv)
            lv.setItemDelegate(delegate)
            lv.setModel(model)
            root_index = model.index(i, 0)
            title = root_index.data()
            lv.setRootIndex(root_index)
            w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
            vlay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(title))
            vlay.addWidget(lv)
            splitter.addWidget(w)
        # To understand better the structure of the model
        # uncomment the following lines
        # treeview = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        # treeview.setModel(model)
        # treeview.expandAll()
        # lay.addWidget(treeview, 2, 0, 1, 5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will take some time to study this and try to implimen it, and If I have questions I will post them here.